# will export function() be called multiple times in javascript?

Tags: javascript, import, export

I wonder if this

```
const getData = () => {
  const data = 1; // simplified complicated operations 
  return data;
};

export default getData();
```

is any performance difference than this:

```
const getData = () => {
  const data = 1;
  return data;
};

const toexport = getData(); // cache to a variable before exporting
export default toexport;
```

The question boils down to *how export actually works*. I read many articles and I can manage to make it work, but I haven't understood what it does under the hood *(couldn't find an article about my question)*.

What if an export is imported from difference `import`, will the `getData()` be called once or being called for each import?

```js
function getData() {
  console.log('getData');
  return 1;
}

// will `export default getData();` be like this
const importSomeWhere = getData();
const importSomeWhereElse = getData();



// or this?
const exportCached = getData();

const importSomeWhere2 = exportCached;
const importSomeWhereElse2 = exportCached;
```

Comment: It will only be called once.

Comment: @AluanHaddad thank you how did you know it? btw is there any article suggested about this topic. Like in C++, `#include` means *copy and paste*, when I include a header file in C++ I know exactly what's happening... But in javascript I don't know how `import` `export` *(kinda equivalent)* work. I can only find articles about *what's the difference between export and module.export, export vs export default* etc. but can't find one about *how it works*

Comment: Modules are a complicated subject. In JavaScript they have certain semantics, C++ includes are completely different and are not modules at all. incidentally, this is one of the many reasons why C++ is getting a proper module system... finally. Regarding JavaScript, most of the literature on modules is technical or overly simplistic. You can find out from the ecmascript specification.  as to how I know about it, wasting years of my life thinking about it, researching it, and discussing it with people on GitHub

Answer (score 3):

It will be evaluated only once. Here's example from [What Happens When a Module Is Imported Twice?](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-module-import-twice/)

In increment.js, we declare a variable called counter

```
let counter = 0;
counter++;

export default counter;
```

In consumer.js we import 2 times, but the counter is evaluated once for the first import

```
import counter1 from './increment';
import counter2 from './increment';

counter1; // => 1
counter2; // => 1
```